# Calculadora que pase a Notación Polaca Inversa

Tags: java

disculpen las molestias pero mi código me esta dando unos problemas de consola y ya no se que moverle para que me muestre lo que quiero.

Mi objetivo es hacer una calculadora que reciba una operación aritmética, la convierta a Notación Polaca Inversa y me de el resultado. Pero al intentar correrlo me da problemas.

Llevo varios días trabajando en esto, con ayuda pero no consigo que funcione de manera correcta.

Aquí les dejo el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculadora {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Ingrese una expresión matemática: ");
        String expresion = scanner.nextLine();

        List<String> postfija = convertirPostfija(expresion);
        double resultado = evaluarPostfija(postfija);

        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
    }

    public static List<String> convertirPostfija(String expresion) {
        Stack<String> pila = new Stack<>();
        List<String> postfija = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] tokens = expresion.split(" ");

        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (esOperador(token)) {
                while (!pila.isEmpty() && prioridad(token) <= prioridad(pila.peek())) {
                    postfija.add(pila.pop());
                }
                pila.push(token);
            } else if (token.equals("(")) {
                pila.push(token);
            } else if (token.equals(")")) {
                while (!pila.isEmpty() && !pila.peek().equals("(")) {
                    postfija.add(pila.pop());
                }
                pila.pop();
            } else {
                postfija.add(token);
            }
        }

        while (!pila.isEmpty()) {
            postfija.add(pila.pop());
        }

        return postfija;
    }

    public static double evaluarPostfija(List<String> postfija) {
        Stack<Double> pila = new Stack<>();

        for (String token : postfija) {
            if (esOperador(token)) {
                double b = pila.pop();
                double a = pila.pop();
                double resultado = aplicarOperador(a, b, token);
                pila.push(resultado);
            } else {
                double numero = Double.parseDouble(token);
                pila.push(numero);
            }
        }

        return pila.pop();
    }

    public static boolean esOperador(String token) {
        return token.equals("+") || token.equals("-") || token.equals("*") || token.equals("/")
                || token.equals("^") || token.equals("sqrt") || token.equals("sin") || token.equals("_");
    }

    public static int prioridad(String operador) {
        switch (operador) {
            case "+":
            case "-":
                return 1;
            case "*":
            case "/":
                return 2;
            case "^":
            case "sqrt":
            case "sin":
            case "_":
                return 3;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public static double aplicarOperador(double a, double b, String operador) {
        switch (operador) {
            case "+":
                return a + b;
            case "-":
                return a - b;
            case "*":
                return a * b;
            case "/":
                return a / b;
            case "^":
                return Math.pow(a, b);
            case "sqrt":
                return Math.sqrt(b);
            case "sin":
                return Math.sin(b);
            case "_":
                return -b;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que me aparece al intentar correrlo
[image: Esto es lo que me aparece al intentar correrlo]

Comment: Que es lo que introduces en tu programa como expresión matemática, puedes dar un ejemplo?

Comment: no se distingue el error

Comment: No me dan las gafas para leer la captura de pantalla.

Comment: Agrega mejor como texto el error que obtienes para que lo pueda visualizar correctamente la comunidad.

Comment: Tanto el código como los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes (ni ver letras tan pequeñas...)

Comment: Hola Fuentes Soriano Misael, Ayer realizaste una pregunta similar, corregí tu código para que funcionara, hoy traes los mismos errores que tenias ayer... realmente quieres que funcione?... por ej: en ***convertirPostfija*** creas la variable **pila**, 4 lineas después, dentro del while, quieres sacarle algo con **pop** y nunca le ingresas datos, es lógico que tu programa no funcione.

Answer (score 2):

El problema principal es que al introducir los valores, para que se detecte cuando un "token" es un operador o un número, los valores deben introducirse usando espacios, ya que de esta forma se separan correctamente de acuerdo al código:

```
String[] tokens = expresion.split(" ");
```

Si no separas los valores que introduces, puedes obtener un `NumberFormatException`, no debes modificar tu código simplemente introduce usando espacios los numeros y operadores, por ejemplo:

```
Ingrese una expresión matemática:  12 * 2 + 1
```

salida:

```
El resultado es: 25.0
```

Ejemplo:

```
Ingrese una expresión matemática: 24 / 2 - 2
```

salida:

```
El resultado es: 10.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifica String[] tokens = expresion.split(" "); por
("(?<=[-+*/^()])|(?=[-+*/^()])");

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/404922)